# mongodb push items to the top of the an aggregate collection

Tags: mongodb

i have a type of document which have an aggregate array which i am limiting to 200 elements that have the most recent date , whenever i add new items to this array i sort by date and slice, and i am liiting it to 200 for performance, but i want to increase the limit and the size is not a problem since they are simple objects with 7 elements maximum, my question is:

i want avoid calling `$sort` because i think its too expensive and directly call `$slice`, because i see no point in sorting by date, but the problem is the most recent items get added to the bottom of the array, is there a way to add the items to the top of the array?

that way it will be sorted without calling `$sort` and i can `$slice` directly.

Comment: you want to keep increasing the array size then? or you want to still keep 200 most whatever?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky exactly so thats why i use slice, but i want to avoid calling sort, i use puch each to add items to the array but they get added to the buttom, i want to add them to the top so i get a natural order without having to call sort, i want to keep more than 200, 2000 if i could but i am aware of the 16MB limitation per document, and i have about 840000 of documents with similar schema and i am sharding across 4 machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this without sorting in 2.4 or earlier, but in the next major version [the `$push` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/push/#modifiers) will have [additional capabilities](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position), including pushing to the *front* of the array, which is likely what you want to do, if you are always inserting later dates than those previously stored.

The functionality is available in development build 2.5.3 and later, but those are not stable production builds, so I would recommend trying the functionality out in it, but don't deploy to production until 2.6 is out.

Comment: great i am not in a hurry! any idea when, i am ok with using 2.5.3, any idea when they final release will come out?

Comment: 2.5.4. was out a while back, 2.5.5 will be out any day now, and that's the last of dev releases, next one will be 2.6.0

Comment: Thanks a lot! glad to know its coming i will use sort for now